# Is multiple ecryptfs encryption possible?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, dm-crypt, cryptsetup, ecryptfs

**Is multiple ecryptfs encryption possible?**

How to encrypt a folder called `level2` with `ecryptfs` that is inside a `ecryptfs` mounted folder called `level1`?

`level1` and `level2` folder are organized as

```
# tree
/root/    
  └─level1
    └─level2
```

and level1 is encrypted with ecryptfs:

```
# mount -t ecryptfs /root/level1 /root/level1
```

I am however unable to mount `level2` folder

```
# mount -t ecryptfs level2 
Passphrase: 
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [d3f92227db598fd6]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d3f92227db598fd6
  ecryptfs_passthrough
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=32
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=d3f92227db598fd6
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /root/level1/level2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
Error mounting eCryptfs: [-1] Operation not permitted
Check your system logs; visit <http://ecryptfs.org/support.html>
```

And   dmesg | tail gives me

```
[...]
[36057.561958] Mount on filesystem of type eCryptfs explicitly disallowed due to known incompatibilities
[36057.562176] Reading sb failed; rc = [-22]
```

PS:  I am only interested in `ecryptfs` encryption. Please don't advice me to use `EncFS` (it works for multiple encryption but is not a secured encryption system) or full partition encryption.